# MySQL WHERE RAND() Behaviour

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table `foo`:

```
 a   b   v
 0   9   1
10  19   2
20  29   3
30  39   4
40  49   5
50  59   6
60  69   7
70  79   8
80  89   9
90 100  10
```

`a` and `b` are the lower and upper boundaries of a certain value `v`. Example:

```
x = 79 => v = 8
```

This can be done with the following statement:

```
SELECT `v`
FROM `foo`
WHERE  79 BETWEEN `a` AND `b`
```

Which MySQL correctly returns:

```
v
8
```

For each number between 0 and 100 provided as input, MySQL will correctly return one, and only one number between 1 and 10.

## Issue

However, if the input number is substituted with a random number generator, the behaviour is somewhat different:

```
SELECT `v`
FROM `foo`
WHERE ROUND(RAND()*100) BETWEEN `a` AND `b`
```

Instead of returning only one number, MySQL might return anything from empty result set up to 3 numbers!

**Question 1**
Is this the expected behaviour of the RAND() statement? What is the reasoning for this apparently weird behavior?

**Question 2**
Considering the intended purpose, is the statement correct? What would be the correct one? How to correct this behaviour?

Comment: It is expected that non-deterministic functions are evaluated every time for every row.

Comment: "How to correct this behaviour?" --- generate a random number in a nested query and inner join it.

Comment: @zerkms How many rows are being evaluated? Sometimes it doesn't return any solution at all, while sometimes it return 3 solutions ...

Comment: It is evaluated for every row in a table.

Comment: @zerkms _It is evaluated for every row in a table._ Ok, but why sometimes it returns an empty solution set? The random numbers can only be between 0 and 100 ...

Comment: @MarkMessa That's strange, but I didn't see this when testing your original query.

Comment: Because it is random for every row. Imagine it returns `90` for the first row, and `0` for all the rest.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's not strange. Every row gets its random number. Their query can return `0..all` rows.

Comment: http://rextester.com/YOIW49684 here is an "ansi"-friendly-version

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen _"How can zero rows be returned?"_ Still doesn't make sense for me either. However, after running several times, I've obtained the following number of answers for each execution: `0 0 0 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 0 1 2 0 0 1` => Therefore, 50% was an empty solution set.

Comment: @MarkMessa http://rextester.com/GTEU6262 - does this make it more obvious? Take the value from the first column and apply the `BETWEEN a AND b` predicate to it

Comment: @zerkms Ok, I guess I understand your point. My only issue now is whether it makes sense getting so many empty solution set. I understand why they are possible, but does 50% of times makes sense?

Comment: @MarkMessa the probability of getting an empty set in your case is 34.87% (given the `RAND()` is truly random and uniform)

Comment: @MarkMessa I think `91/100` is a better approximation. But yep ;-)

Comment: @MarkMessa I totally am not agree :-) `RAND()*100` generates values in the `[0; 100)` range. So it's `91/100`. Roughly, because it's an open interval on the right, and closed on the left.

Comment: @MarkMessait is `[0; 1)`. So `RAND() * 100` generates `[0; 1)`. So it's `9/100` chance to get into the `[0; 9)` range, and `91/100` chance to get to the `[10; 100)` range.

Comment: @MarkMessa oops, sorry, I did not notice you have `ROUND` there. Why did you put it there? It makes the random distribution not uniform. If you want to generate random integers you should use `FLOOR` and extend the range to 101. `FLOOR(RAND() * 101)` would generate uniform integers in the `[0; 100]` range.

Comment: @MarkMessa I'm not sure what we're discussing here, really :-) It was not an issue, and it's not an issue at the moment. I'm just saying that usually no one wants that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ansi-sql-friendly solution with a single query would look like

```
SELECT x.rnd, `v`
FROM yourTable y
INNER JOIN (SELECT RAND()*100 rnd) x
WHERE x.rnd BETWEEN y.`a` AND y.`b`;
```

it generates a random value just once and then is used in a joined query.

Demo: http://rextester.com/YOIW49684

The query and the base table are kindly borrowed from [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oops, sorry, my changes overwrote yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same random value to be applied to every row of the query, then one option is to use a session variable:

```
SET @rnd = RAND()*100;
SELECT v
FROM foo
WHERE ROUND(@rnd) BETWEEN a AND b;
```

### Demo

Comment: Do phpMyAdmin accept mixing `set` and `select` in a single query box? Do I have to create a procedure to test your session variable idea?